# Using if endif for my ie stylesheet is not working. html/css

Tags: css, internet-explorer

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="style.css" />
```

while using this, the content in IE is also affected by style.css and ie.css, i'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is supposed to be.

You have some HTML which is only for IE, and some that it for general use.

The usually approach is to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /> 
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

And have ie.css contain a tiny amount of CSS to fix things that break with the general stylesheet.

If you really want to have completely separate stylesheets then:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" /> 
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: yeah, for some reason IE is weird responding to some padding issues that is different for other browsers. thanks!

Comment: If the padding issues are that the padding is inside the height/width instead of around it, that usually means you have a Doctype that triggers Quirks mode (or no Doctype at all). If so, you should fix that problem instead of supplying a different stylesheet.